# Book recommendation for Olympiad inequalities?

Tags: inequality, book-recommendation

I have searched a lot about books on Olympiad inequalities..
And I have finalized 3 books

***1) Secrets in inequalities by pham Kim hung***

***2) inequalities a problem solving approach by bj Venkatachala***

***3) Cevtkovski inequalities***

Because inequalities is declining recently in Olympiads that's why I cannot do more than 1 book ....

All above mentioned three books satisfy what I want i.e they have almost all important inequalities then solved examples and techniques and then lots of problems with solution...so I am not able to decide which to choose ...
Any Suggestions from anyone who has read above books???

Thankyou

Answer (score 3):

In my opinion, the first book is a best between these books.

I need also to say that in the book of Pham Kim Hung with beautiful problems and beautiful solutions there are wrong solutions, but this fact not so disturbs.

The volume 2 you can see here:

http://gil.ro/downloadable/download/sample/sample_id/1/

The best book, I think, it's the Vasile Cirtoaje's book: "Mathematical Inequalities", 2018, 5 volumes.

Comment: Ok, but  problem with secrets in inequalities is first of all it is published more than 10 years ago!! Don't you think that methods are very old...and second that I find pdf of volume 1 only...I did not see pdf of volume 2 ?

Comment: @User84463  If you want to work with new methods, so for which there are books and papers of Vasile Cirtoaje.

Comment: Ok, I will check it..but is there a problem in second book which I have mention ? Because it has new methods, new techniques and 300+ problems with solution in it..and also it is made by Indian IMO team leader...

Comment: @User84463 If you look for problems, which you have mention,  so you always can find it in any book.

Comment: @User84463 Work with this book. It's a good book. Good luck!